# I try to replace the delete button tag to anchor tag but it's was not worked

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

**deleting action form can't worked** I think but i try to solve this error but unsuccessful

My Delete button tag code that's in working condition in front end and back end . But when i use anchor tag on the replace button the not worked.

I put both code that's first is delete button code in working condition and second is my anchor tag code.

```
<td>
     <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{action('PostController@destroy', $row['id'])}}">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
     </form>
 </td>
```

this is my anchor code code that's not worked

```
  <td>
 <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{action('PostController@destroy', $row['id'])}}">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
 </form>
</td>
```

error message on address bar of browser:- mywebsite/posts/id=1
Delete action can't performed.
I want to use this font awesome icon in my all project but in this field anchor tag not worked

```
<i class="fa fa-trash">
```

Comment: why did you change your code which was working fine ?

Comment: anchor tag generally redirects to url not submit. share your exact intension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing some tags, So If you want to submit form using `anchor`, use this

```
<td>
 <form method="post" id="my_form" class="delete_form" action="{{action('PostController@destroy', $row['id'])}}">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" /> 
   <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit();"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
 </form>
</td>
```